# Why are Indicator Random Variables better that Random Variables when analyzing algorithms?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I understand the idea behind a random variable and the indicator random variable. BUT my question is why use indicator random variables if we have random variables? How do these indicator random variables make life that much easier? Note I know very basic statistics mean, mode etc and understand probability but I've never done statistics in depth.

I'm currently using the Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition by Cormen et al and the indicator random variables and random variables are introduced with this problem:

*

> Suppose that you need to hire a new office assistant. Your previous
>   attempts at hiring have been unsuccessful, and you decide to use an
>   employment agency. The employment agency sends you one candidate each
>   day. You interview that person and then decide either to hire that
>   person or not. You must pay the employment agency a small fee to
>   interview an applicant. To actually hire an applicant is more costly,
>   however, since you must fire your current office assistant and pay a
>   substantial hiring fee to the employment agency. You are committed to
>   having, at all times, the best possible person for the job. Therefore,
>   you decide that, after interviewing each applicant, if that applicant
>   is better qualified than the current office assistant, you will fire
>   the current office assistant and hire the new applicant. You are
>   willing to pay the resulting price of this strategy, but you wish to
>   estimate what that price will be

- They then look to solve the problem but state that using the following:

[image]

would be cumbersome and that an indicator random variable would be of better use. I can't seem to see how the indicator random variable is of better use...

Comment: Are they? $ $ $ $

Comment: Touche. In the introduction to algorithms textbook they state that indicator random variables are better suited to solve problems over random variables. I'm wondering why?

Comment: Which textbook? At present, your reformulation is too vague to be made much of.

Comment: @Did posted the problem

Comment: Ah, but this is a statement with a *very restricted context*, not at all in the generality you let us believe. The authors refer to the fact that, when $X$ is nonnegative and integer valued and $P(X\geqslant x)$ is simple to write down, one can, yes, prefer the alternative formula $$E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X\geqslant x).$$